# Truly wipe Docker cache

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am debugging my Dockerfile, so I want my `cat`'s and `ls`'s to actually print something.

Unfortunately, me doing `docker system prune -a` and using `--no-cache` flag for `docker build` do nothing. Docker did pruned quite a lot, but the majority of build steps are still `CACHED`.

Is there another way to wipe out cache? Or to tell Docker to use a specific cache, that is purposefully does not exist? Or to change the Dockerfile so Docker will not use the cache?